# Differentiable function with negative derivative but non-decreasing

Tags: derivatives

I have to give an example of differentiable function $f:[-1;1]\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with negative derivative but this at the same  time this function has to be non-decreasing. Is it even possible?

Comment: post the example and we see. But if you really mean monotone non-decreasing and negative derivative and not non-positive, then no, it can't be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$? On $[-1,1]\setminus \{0\}$ the derivative is $-x^{-2}$ which is negative. But $f$ is not decreasing since $f(a)<f(b)$ for $a<0<b$.

Comment: That function is not decreasing. But it does not follow that it's non-decreasing! It's not non-decreasing. (Of course it seems very likely that the OP made the same error in his post - surely he was asked to give a function which was not decreasing, not a non-decreasing function...)